# How does XUnit RetryFact attribute works?

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit

I have Selenium tests which are run by XUnit. I write tests on c#. Some of the tests are not stable (especially those which uses mouse actions). I found the RetryFactAttribute in XUnit but I can't find any documetation for it.

My main question for now: will xUnit run other tests while waiting 3 seconds if I use `[RetryFact(delayBetweenRetriesMs: 3000)]` ?

If you can, please suggest resource where I can find more information about the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an example of how to use a custom `IXunitTestCaseDiscoverer` and `XunitTestCase`. You can find the example source code [here](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/413e29ab744a354bc26aee2b8748b16d3ef969e6/RetryFactExample).

Ultimately it's just an attribute with the following attribute attached to it:

```cs
[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("RetryFactExample.RetryFactDiscoverer", "RetryFactExample")]
```

Which then indirectly references [RetryTestCase.cs](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/413e29ab744a354bc26aee2b8748b16d3ef969e6/RetryFactExample/RetryTestCase.cs) (a derivative of `XunitTestCase`) where its actual behaviour is defined:

```cs
public override async Task<RunSummary> RunAsync(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink,
                                                IMessageBus messageBus,
                                                object[] constructorArguments,
                                                ExceptionAggregator aggregator,
                                                CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    var runCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // This is really the only tricky bit: we need to capture and delay messages (since those will
        // contain run status) until we know we've decided to accept the final result;
        var delayedMessageBus = new DelayedMessageBus(messageBus);

        var summary = await base.RunAsync(diagnosticMessageSink, delayedMessageBus, constructorArguments, aggregator, cancellationTokenSource);
        if (aggregator.HasExceptions || summary.Failed == 0 || ++runCount >= maxRetries)
        {
            delayedMessageBus.Dispose();  // Sends all the delayed messages
            return summary;
        }

        diagnosticMessageSink.OnMessage(new DiagnosticMessage("Execution of '{0}' failed (attempt #{1}), retrying...", DisplayName, runCount));
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about your question re whether it will block on a single test for 3 seconds, but judging by this I think the answer is probably "yes". It's best to test this experimentally to be sure.